# Laravel code organization

Tags: laravel-5

I want to organize Laravel code into below folder structure for the sake of easy maintenance and better grouping. I do not know whether I can do this in Laravel.

```
app
--order
----CustomerOrder.php
----CustomerOrderController.php
----CustomerOrderService.php
--purchasing
----PurchaseOrder.php
----PurchaseOrderController.php
----PurchaseOrderService.php
```

Can I modify configuration files to facilitate above hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is a MVC-based framework.  The controllers and models are placed in different folders as the documents instruct:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure

I suggest you organize and group your project folder structure according to Laravel document.  The readability and maintenance will be much easier if everyone using the same folder structure in same framework rather than the customized structure.

Comment: I love Laravel. But I want to group code based on what it does (function) not based on what it is. That's simply what I am looking for...

Comment: I agree with @howar31's answer, though I understand what you want, but if you really want to go that way, you are going to have a bad time writing all the includes and references, and in the end, you will end up with a hard-to-maintain code